# How to control Primary Menu links using Secondary Menu's Drupal 6?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I got a secondary menu with two items "English" & "Spanish" and Primary Menu with main site links.

We are not using Langauage transliation, we got separate records in database for each langauages.

So how can I make all Primary Menu links to select appropriate nodes(for each languages) when user select the secondary menu ?

That's is there any way to change the primary menu links while selecting the secondary menu ? or replace primary menu items using secondary menu ?

Please give me any info on this topic which can lead me to do this task !

Answer (score 1):

That would take an awful lot of coding, you should use the transliteration module for this. If you don't you'll just end up rewriting a significant portion of that module just to get exactly the same functionality.

Don't reinvent the wheel, if a solution has already been made for your problem - use it!

Comment: **is there anyway to change primary menu items with respect to secondary menu item ?**

Comment: Putting it in bold won't help, the answer above still applies!

Comment: sorry clive putting my question in bold I was only asking to you, so it is not possible ! anyway thanks for the reply

Comment: :) It's totally possible (pretty much anything is with Drupal), it's just it would take a fair bit of coding to accomplish and I'd suggest using translation instead of writing it yourself, as they've already done the work for you. Best of luck!

Comment: **I tried to configure Primary Menu Link block to appear on listed pages but still its showing in all pages ? How can I do this ? Also I created a new menu and added it in block to visible it in header but its not showing up ? Is there anything else to be done ?**

Comment: somehow I got this [link]http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12550/how-can-i-hide-the-primary-menu-block-to-certain-pages-using-php thanx to all for help.